# 'Id is malformed' on UpdateAsync

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am starting out in MS Graph. I have below code to pick up all mail messages from Inbox of a specific user. Then I go through each message, process it and set its Subject. When I try to save back message using UpdateAsync I get an 'Id is malformed' exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Regards

```
 var inboxMessages = await graphClient
   .Users[user.Id]
   .MailFolders.Inbox
   .Messages
   .Request()
   .OrderBy("receivedDateTime DESC")
   .GetAsync();

 foreach(Microsoft.Graph.Message x in inboxMessages) {

   //Process message

   // ...

   x.Subject = "Processed: " + x.Subject

   //Save changes to message Subject
   await graphClient
     .Users[user.Id]
     .MailFolders.Inbox
     .Messages["{x.Id}"]
     .Request()
     .UpdateAsync(x);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `$` before `"{x.Id}"` when you try to use string interpolation. You do not send id but only string `"{x.Id}"`.
It should be

```
//Save changes to message Subject
await graphClient
 .Users[user.Id]
 .MailFolders.Inbox
 .Messages[$"{x.Id}"]
 .Request()
 .UpdateAsync(x);
```